# Set default file name for a PFD document created with pdf lib by Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf-lib.js

I generate a PDF document using the following code snippet and it is kept loaded to a HTML iFrame.

Then user can download it if required.
[image]

I want to set the document number as the default file name. But I could not find a proper solution to set the filename using PDF-LIB library.

```html
<html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/pdf-lib"></script>
      </head>
    
      <body>
        <div style="display: flex; width: 100%; height: 100%; flex-direction: column; overflow: hidden;">
            <iframe id="pdf" title="myTest PDF" style="flex-grow: 1; border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;"></iframe>
        </div>
      </body>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/pdf-lib@1.17.1/dist/pdf-lib.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        createPdf();
        async function createPdf() {
          const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.create();
          pdfDoc.setSubject('PDF Subject');
          pdfDoc.setTitle('PDF Title');
          const page = pdfDoc.addPage([350, 400]);
          page.moveTo(110, 200);
          page.drawText('Hello World!');
          const pdfDataUri = await pdfDoc.saveAsBase64({ dataUri: true
         });
          document.getElementById('pdf').src = pdfDataUri;
        }
      </script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be posible to set the filename in the browsers iframe as that is usually outside of js controls. However, you can on render trigger "download.js ()" with a given filename that will do that with a similar result.

[image]

Optionally set the iFrame title (makes no material difference but more conformant).

```
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>myTest PDF</title>
      </head>
```

Ensure scripts includes /download.js (you should use your own /local copy).

```
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/pdf-lib@1.17.1/dist/pdf-lib.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://danml.com/js/download.js"></script>
```

Then at the end or rendering script add the desired file name.

```
          });
          document.getElementById('pdf').src = pdfDataUri;

          // No matter the input format, download() saves a file using the specified file name and mime
          // information in the same manner as a server, using a Content-Disposition HTTP header.

          download(pdfDataUri, "myTest PDF.pdf", "application/pdf");
        }
```